# How do I resolve this VirtualBox PIT: speaker: cannot open

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, virtualbox, audio

Inside of `VBox.log`, I have the following.

> PIT: speaker: cannot open "/dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr", errno=13

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error (`13`, `EACCES`) is a "Permission denied" error. You're seeing it because the user that you're running VirtualBox as does not have permissions to write to that file.

## Correcting the Permissions on the PC Speaker Device File

The file `/dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr` is actually just a symlink, use `ls -lH` to see who owns the file

```
ls -lH /dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 79 Jun  6 14:16 /dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr
```

In this case, you can see you need to be in the `input` group to write to the file.

Run the commands `groups` to see what groups you're in. If you do **not** see the group listed above, you'll have to add yourself to that group. To do that simply run the following,

```
usermod -aG input "$USER"
```

This will add your user to the `input` group. Now **log off and log back in**. When you log back in you may have to **`modprobe pcspkr`** again if the `pcspkr` is in your blaclist. Check that the file exists, and if it does run VirtualBox, the log should now have,

```
PIT: speaker: opened "/dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr"
```